# A step in Lurie's treatment of $L$-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, infinity-categories

I am looking at Proposition 3 of Lecture 6 from Lurie's course *Algebraic L-theory and Surgery* ([https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/287xnotes/Lecture6.pdf](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/287xnotes/Lecture6.pdf)).  This involves a stable $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$, a finite set $S$, and a diagram of objects $X(T)\in\mathcal{C}$ indexed by nonempty subsets $T\subseteq S$ with restriction maps $X(T)\to X(U)$ when $\emptyset\neq U\subseteq T\subseteq S$.  (All this is to be interpreted in the usual $\infty$-categorical way.) I'll take $S=\{0,1,2\}$ and write $X_{01}$ for $X(\{0,1\})$ and so on.  I'll also define $X_\emptyset$ to be the colimit of $X(T)$ for $T\neq\emptyset$, so we have a homotopy cocartesian cubical diagram as follows.

[image]

We now define $Y(T)$ to be the colimit of $X(U)$ over nonempty subsets $U\subseteq T$, except that in the case $T=\emptyset$ we define $Y(\emptyset)=X(S)$.  This means that
\begin{align*}
 Y_\emptyset &= X_{012} \\
 Y_0 &= X_0 & Y_1 &= X_1 & Y_2 &= X_2 \\
 Y_{01} &= X_0\cup_{X_{01}}X_1 & 
 Y_{02} &= X_0\cup_{X_{02}}X_2 & 
 Y_{12} &= X_1\cup_{X_{12}}X_2 \\
 Y_{012} &= X_\emptyset
\end{align*}

One can check that these fit together into a new cubical diagram as follows.

[image]

Lurie states that this is again homotopy cocartesian (and hence also homotopy cartesian by stability, which is what he really wants).  He says that this follows ``by unwinding the definitions'', and spells out how it works in the case $|S|=2$, where it is indeed obvious.  The corresponding statement for classical colimits in the category of sets is also not very hard, but here we are essentially looking at a homotopy colimit, which is more subtle.  Consider, for example, the case where $X_{012}=A$ and $X(T)=0$ for $\emptyset\neq T\neq\{0,1,2\}$, which gives $X_\emptyset=\Sigma^2A$.  We find that $Y(T)$ is also zero for $\emptyset\neq T\neq\{0,1,2\}$ and so the claimed conclusion is true but things do not fit together in a very obvious way.

I think that I can see a proof of the claim involving a bit of a detour, but it is not consistent with the claim that we just need to unfold the definitions.  Can anyone suggest a better way to think about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to see it which might constitute "just unfolding the definitions" (at least if one were sitting in on the class at Harvard when it was being taught).

Set $Z(T) = Y(T^c)$, (compliment taken in $S$). Then the cube of $X$'s and the cube of $Z$'s are indexed on the same thing, making it easier to compare.

Consider the colimit of the $Z(T)$'s. We have:

$$ \varinjlim_{\substack{T \subseteq S \\ T \neq \emptyset}} Z(T) =\varinjlim_{\substack{T \subseteq S \\ T \neq \emptyset}} Y(T^c) =  \varinjlim_{\substack{T \subseteq S \\ T \neq \emptyset}}  \varinjlim_{\substack{U \subseteq S \\ U \neq \emptyset \\ \textrm{either } U \subseteq T^c \\ \textrm{ or } T=S=U  }} X(U)$$
$$  =  \varinjlim_{\substack{T, U \subseteq S \\ T, U \neq \emptyset \\ \textrm{either } T \cap U = \emptyset} \\ \textrm{ or } T=S=U } X(U)  \stackrel{\star}{=}  \varinjlim_{\substack{U \subseteq S \\ U \neq \emptyset}} X(U)  \cong X_\emptyset = Z_\emptyset$$

This is what we wanted to show.

(Quick aside, I wish I knew how to make a proper colimit operation with MathJax).

The only identification that is non-trivial is $\star$, and this uses an $\infty$-finality argument.

There is a forgetful functor from the strange category of pairs to the category of non-empty subsets of $S$ which just remembers the subset $U$. I claim that this is an $\infty$-final functor (cofinal in Lurie's HTT terminology). Then, since the functor of which we are taking the colimit on the left-hand side of the $\star$ factors through this forgetful functor, we have that $\star$ is an equivalence.

To see that the forgetful functor is $\infty$-final, we need to see that certain under categories have contractible classifying spaces (see the [n-lab page on $\infty$-final functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+%28infinity%2C1%29-functor) for some details, especially thm 4.2). Specifically, we may fix $U_0$ and then consider the category of non-empty pairs $(U,T)$ such that $U \subseteq U_0$ and either $U=T =S$ or $U$ and $T$ are disjoint. The former can only happen when $U_0=S$, and in this case there is an initial object $U=T=S$ (morphisms are the reverse of inclusions). So that case has contractible classifying space, and we must show the same is true for $U_0 \neq S$.

For $U_0 \neq S$ we have a zig-zag of natural transformations between functors: (here we denote their value on a pair $(U,T)$, the first is the identity functor, the last is the constant functor):

$$ (U,T) \leftarrow (U, T \cup U_0^c) \to (U, U_0^c) \leftarrow (U_0, U^c_0) $$

This shows that the classifying space of these under categories is indeed contractible, so that the forgetful functor is $\infty$-final, as claimed.